# Golang Dockerfile permission denied

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I it seems like there is an error in the permission distribution on my Dockerfile and i can't seem to resolve it.

here is the error

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/my-app": permission denied: unknown
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```sh
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

##
## Build
##
FROM golang:1.19rc2-buster AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY src/go.mod ./
COPY src/go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY src/*.go ./

RUN go build -o /my-app

##
## Deploy
##
FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian10

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=build /my-app /my-app

USER nonroot:nonroot

ENTRYPOINT ["/my-app"]
```

and here is my docker-compose

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  golang:
    container_name: golang
    build:
      dockerfile: go.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    depends_on:
      - cassandra
    restart: always
  cassandra:
    container_name: cassandra
    image: cassandra:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9042:9042
```

Comment: What does the Go source look like; is it `package main` or something else?  Can you run that `go build` command successfully outside of Docker and get a running executable?

Comment: Can u make that an answer David Maze, so i can validate the answer for you, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that your go code contain a

```
package main
```